# What is the longest possible sequence of consecutive checks without captures?

Tags: records, check, captures

The best known answer (54) for arbitrary checking moves is given in [What is the theoretical limit for the number of consecutive checks?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8982/what-is-the-theoretical-limit-for-the-number-of-consecutive-checks), but I'm interested in sequences without captures.
As usual, the initial position and all moves must be legal.

Answer (score 3):

From the SuperProblem.net [*Book of Records of Chess Composition*](http://superproblem.ru/archive/S_record.html) "Unusual Records" section, we find the known answer of **17 checks** by Alexey Khanyan.

```
[Title " Alexey Khanyan, SuperProblem.net, 17 Captureless Consecutive Checks"]
[FEN "b2Rr2q/1r1B4/RP1k2NQ/4b2b/bR3Npr/B1RK4/n1r4B/1b1R4 b - - 0 1"]
[startflipped ""]

1... Bb5+ 2. Rbc4+ Nb4+ 3. Ke4+ Rd2+ 4. Rd3+ Bd4+ 5. Ne7+ Bg6+ 6. Bf5+ Rd7+ 7. b7+ Bc6+ 8. Nfd5+ g3+ 9. Qf4+ Qe5+
```